# Send 'variable' data between different objects in Java

Tags: java, json, database, events, service

I am currently working on building an API in Java that consumes event-data from other services (source services). Each of the source services can send different data, i.e.

Service 1 sends: `{int int String}`

Service 2 sends: `{int String boolean String}` ...

Is there an efficient way to send/receive the data given that my service can accept only one input argument.

I was thinking of sending the data as a JSON object, however as the data itself can vary, I do not know how to parse it effectively.

The ultimate goal is to store the data in a column database for all the variables sent by the source services, with minimal changes required at the source.

The source service can be as simple as-

```
public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int fileCount = 1273;
        String diskName = "MyDisk";  
    }
}
```

where `{int String}` needs to be packaged and sent. So finally after my API processes the input, it should store the data in a table -

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTh7l.png)

Comment: Could you show a sample 'Source'?

Comment: You could always create some `Parameter` class (most likely abstract) or interface and extend/implement it for each of your `Consumer`s. But this seems like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You could create a serializable POJO (for the data in each Source Service). These POJOS would have to be in separate library that both Source and You have access to. Then when the Source sends the POJO to you (as a JSON or however), you know how to deserialize it. And then depending on the POJO you can write the DB.